# Modify Sender when shared mailbox selected

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server

In outlook, with automapping enabled in exchange, when you select a mailbox and then click on new mail, the default sender is the main account. When you manually mount the shared mailbox, the default sender is the shared mailbox. Thx Microsoft.
To fix that, I'm trying to create a macro in vba. It works, but only once !!
Here is the code :

```
Private WithEvents objinspectors As Outlook.Inspectors

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Set objinspectors = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub objinspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
  If TypeName(Inspector.CurrentItem) = "MailItem" Then
    Set objitem = GetCurrentItem()
    Set originalMailbox = objitem.Parent.Store
    Dim oEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set oEmail = Inspector.CurrentItem
    If oEmail.EntryID = "" And oEmail.ConversationIndex = "" And Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Accounts.Item(1).DisplayName <> objitem.Parent.Store.DisplayName Then
        oEmail.SentOnBehalfOfName = objitem.Parent.Store
        oEmail.Subject = "TEST"
    End If
  End If
  Set objinspectors = Application.Inspectors
  Set objitem = Nothing
  Set oEmail = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
           
    Set objApp = Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select
       
    Set objApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Why are you resetting the `objinspectors` variable?

Comment: That was just in case the objinspector event was resetted after being consumed once. But it's useless. My modification of the subject works everytime (vs the sender  modification working only once), so the problem is not here. I just copy/paste my actual code, but it needs some cleaning. What's "funny" is that if I put a spy on the variable "oEmail.SentOnBehalfOfName", the field IS correctly modified, but when the new mail opens, the sender is me, and not the shared mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not clear why you are getting the currently selected item when you have got one from the `inspector` object:

```
Private Sub objinspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
  If TypeName(Inspector.CurrentItem) = "MailItem" Then
    Set objitem = GetCurrentItem()
```

Instead, you could use the following code in the `NewInspector` event:

```
Set objitem = Inspector.CurrentItem
```

I'd also suggest waiting for the first `Activate` event of the `Inspector` class and grab the item there instead.

To get the currently selected store in Outlook you could use the `ActiveExplorer` property to get an instance of the `Explorer` class and then get the store selected by getting the `Selection` object.

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that out of the box until you configure an additional account in Outlook, not a shared store.

As soon as you configure an additonal account in Outlook you will be able to use the [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property which returns or sets an `Account` object that represents the account under which the `MailItem` is to be sent. In that case a proper account should be chosen by Outlook as well.

Comment: the inspector.currentitem gives me the new created mail (the one I want to modify the sender), and the active explorer item gives me the first mail selected in the explorer, and with that I can get the current selected Mailbox. And I want the new mail to be sent with the current selected mailbox. The way it works when you add the account manually. But I don't want to go back to mounting manually the shared mailboxes for all users. It's a lot of useless work for our technicians. As I said, my code, not perfect, works. But only once...